# How to remove “No mail for user” notifications in Zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Every time I open Zsh I get a “No mail for user” notification. How can I stop them?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, try this. Go into the `mail` directory:

```
$cd /var/mail
```

Then remove the username that has the mail using the command:

```
sudo rm <username>
```